# Get the Case Number when we clicked the Knowledge Article in Case Knowledge Article Related list search box

Tags: salesforce, apex, lwc, lightning

I have a requirement from client that is In Case,  Knowledge Article Search Section is there, In Standard Search of Articles if I open particular knowledge Article I need to get the Case Number from which Case user has searched. How to do that?

I need these details which user has opened and from which case number he has opened

Comment: Did you figure out a way to do it?